# Looking for Angular e2e tslint rulesets

Tags: angular, protractor, eslint, e2e-testing, tslint

Are there some tslint plugins to validate my protractor jasmine e2e test in Angular? 
I just found some [rules for eslint](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor). How can i use these rules in my tslint.json?